# asyncdata function not rendering vuex data on sever side

Tags: javascript, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

After fetching data from vuex store in asyncData() function and checking page source. Data is not showing on page source.

```
<template>
<div>
  <p>{{title}}</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    asyncData({params, store}) {
       return { title: store.state.category.title };
  }
</script>
```

Page source result

`<p>[]</p>`

The expected result should be

`<p> My Category Title </p>`

Is there any fault in my understanding of asyncData() function?

Comment: Try `this.$store.state.category.title` or `import {mapState} from 'vuex'`

Comment: As per the nuxt documentation, we can't access "**this**" inside asyncdata function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of research. I came to know that using `nuxtServerInit()`. We can populate the store directly from the server. 
`If you are using a module pattern you can use it only in store\index.js file.` 
Now if I am fetching vuex store data I can see it in my component page source.
The best part of it is that if you refresh the page then again `nuxtServerInit()` automatically run and populate the store as per the logic defined in this.

Answer (score 0):

i can not understand why you are using `asyncData()` to fetch data from the vuex store. The data that is stored in the vuex store will be stored as long as you are on your website. After leaving or refreshing the site it will load again the initial values.

`àsyncData()` is used for example to fetch data from a database and to display it on your webpage.

And the problem here is, you access the store wrong:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <p>{{$store.state.category.title}}</p>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Actually I am populating store on the home page and for another page, I am fetching data from vuex store. my problem is, The data which I am fetching from the vuex store is not rendering server-side.

One solution is as you mentioned on each page I should use asyncdata to fetch data from the server. But is there any way to make vuex data render on the server side.